# active storage url giving 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am currently using Active Storage to upload images. However, when I attempt to display the image on the Active Admin index, I receive a "No webpage was found for the web address page not found" error on the first attempt. Strangely, when I try again using the same link, the image displays without a problem. It seems like the result is being toggled. Everything works fine in localhost, but I'm experiencing issues in production.

Here is the code I'm using in the model:

```
has_one_attached :logo, dependent: :destroy
```

And the code in my `storage.yml` file:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Here is the code I'm using in the Active Admin index:

```
index do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column :logo, sortable: false do |s|
    if s.logo.attached?
      link_to "Logo Link", url_for(s.logo), target: "_blank"
    else
      "Logo not attached" 
    end
  end
  actions
end
```